# Unitary Matrix for Block Diagonalization

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, linear-algebra, crystals

What is the method used to determine the unitary matrix that block diagonalizes the symmetry operations of a group? I'm sure there's multiple ways to go about it, but finding a source on how one block diagonalizes a matrix has been difficult. We'd like to restrict this to real-valued entries, otherwise we'd simply diagonalize the matrix fully.

For example, looking at the $C_{3v}$ symmetry group:

Let $ \ C_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}, \ \ Q = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt3}&\frac{2}{\sqrt6}&0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt3}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt6}&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt3}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt6}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$ and 
$\ Q^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt3}&\frac{1}{\sqrt3}&\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\\\frac{2}{\sqrt6}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt6}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt6}\\0&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$

Note that $Q$ is unitary. This gives us

$Q^{-1}C_3 Q \ = \ C_3^{'} \ = \ \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{3}{2\sqrt3}\\0&\frac{3}{2\sqrt3}&-\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

the block diagonalized form of $C_3$. My question is, how was $Q$ determined? A push in any helpful direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the general case (and unless your matrix is an undiagonalizable Jordan block) you can just fully diagonalize it directly, though possibly (as in this case) at the cost of having complex entries in $C_3'$. If you want to restrict things to real-valued outcomes (which would then make it reasonable to relax the requirement of full diagnoalization down to block diagonalization) then you should state it explicitly. And, in those cases, you should specify clearly what conditions you expect the blocks to obey (to e.g. rule out the trivial case of $n\times n$ matrices seen as $n\times n$ blocks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect if you posted this in the math SE you'd get excessively systematic and pithy answers, and aim at generality. Here, I'll just remind you what your basic linear algebra text almost certainly covers.

The point is you are meant to immediately observe $C_3$ (is the cyclic shift matrix and so) has the obvious eigenvector (1,1,1)/$\sqrt3$. That means that  the real orthogonal matrix (not merely arbitrary complex unitary one!) consisting of this eigenvector and many two real vectors orthogonal to it and each other will rotate $C_3$ to the space of this eigenvector and the 2×2 subspace of the other two. Since the matrix is real orthogonal by construction, you are there.

So, how do you choose the two real vectors orthogonal to (1,1,1)? It's trivial sudoku; but note your could have chosen, instead (1,1,-2) and (1,-1,0), normalized, instead, etc... Do you see  it?

- Teaching moment. Coincidentally, $C_3$ is the most celebrated [Sylvester nonion shift matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices) ever, 1882, with eigenvalues outlining the Mercedes-Benz sign.

Comment: I certainly do see it now. Leave it to me to dramatically over-complicate a physics question. Thank you so much!